# compute traffic distribution based on performance

Tags: weights

we are trying to come up with a formula for computing weights (traffic distribution) based on performance. Parameters are metrics like cost, reliability (delivery success / total delivery), latency etc.

concrete example:

- link A costs 0.01, reliability is 0.9, latency is 10 ms
- link B costs 0.02, reliability is 0.99, latency is 5 ms

Say Performance of link A is computed as:

```
P(link A) = w1 * cost + w2 * reliability + w3 * latency
```

How do i assign weights to performance. E.g. it starts with 50% traffic to link A & 50 to link B but as performance of some link degrades, we adjust the traffic. we would want the adjustments to be gradual.

looking for some solutions / approaches for this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the question, @Srinivas. Would you mind specifying what do you mean by performance? Is it combination of the metrics that you mentioned? As far as I understood, you want to see how tuple of values of your metrics change with increase of the weight, don't you?

Comment: thanks for your comment. updated the question.